# Log files lead me to nowhere

Tags: uplink

It is a common job to accept that requires you to find the person responsible in hacking their system at a specified time by traversing through each log files in every computer the hacker connected.

My problem now is the log file leads me to nowhere. The last one I checked does not contain any entries that has the same date and time as the specified ones.

I tried redoing the tracing again but it still leads me through the same machine. There isn't even a deleted entry showing that the hacker deleted his logs files.

Is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the last machine a personal computer?  If so you have found the hacker.

If not then it sounds like you waited too long before doing the mission - the hacker will eventually come back and *completely* delete their logs to cover their steps.  From [The Ultimate Uplink Guide](http://guide.modlink.net/section3.php)

> NOTES: If you take one of these missions, make sure it isn't more than
>   a couple of hours old, by checking the date it was posted. **If the
>   mission is too old, it will be impossible, because the hacker will
>   have gone back and totally removed his logs.** Make sure you delete your
>   logs between every connection. Do not leave all the logs until you
>   have finished the mission as you maybe passive traced before you are
>   finished.

Also if it is a bank make sure that you are logging into the admin section

> If the Log points to a bank (or it is an Unauthorised Money
>   transfer mission, which starts at the bank) make sure you hack the
>   admin section and not someone's account. The logs you need cannot be
>   found in an account.

Comment: The last machine is a company owned terminal, so it seems that the hacker did deleted his logs totally.